# Flutter run stuck at installing

Tags: android, flutter, installation

I have a problem installing something on my old Android phone (Sony Xperia Z (C6603)).
I installed a custom rom (Lineage OS, Android 9) so that I can better test.
The problem is, that if I run "flutter run" the build gets stuck at installing:

> Launching lib/main.dart on Xperia Z in debug mode...
>
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       58,3s
>
> ✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
>
> Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
> (This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

The code works fine on my iPhone 12 Pro and on the Android phone of my dad (Sony Xperia XZ Premium, also Android 9).
A new flutter project does also not work.

Things I tried:

- flutter clean
- installing the apk manually and running then flutter run

The phone is completly set up new, so the app was never installed there and can not be on different user profiles (like you see on many other questions/answers with the same problem).
Has someone another idea I could try?

Thank you!

edit:
Output of "flutter run -v":

```
daniel@daniels-mbp testinstall % flutter run -v                       
[ +172 ms] executing: [/Users/daniel/development/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +81 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[       ] 78910062997c3a836feee883712c241a5fd22983
[       ] executing: [/Users/daniel/development/flutter/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[ +127 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[       ] 1.22.5
[  +12 ms] executing: [/Users/daniel/development/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[       ] origin/stable
[       ] executing: [/Users/daniel/development/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +18 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +163 ms] executing: [/Users/daniel/development/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +43 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[       ] stable
[  +33 ms] executing: sw_vers -productName
[  +53 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productName
[       ] macOS
[       ] executing: sw_vers -productVersion
[  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productVersion
[   +1 ms] 11.1
[       ] executing: sw_vers -buildVersion
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -buildVersion
[       ] 20C69
[   +1 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[  +11 ms] Exit code 1 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[       ] sysctl: unknown oid 'hw.optional.arm64'
[ +109 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[  +13 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +51 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +11 ms] executing: /usr/bin/xcode-select --print-path
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/xcode-select --print-path
[       ] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
[   +1 ms] executing: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
[+1606 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
[       ] Xcode 12.3
           Build version 12C33
[   +3 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[   +6 ms] Exit code 1 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[       ] sysctl: unknown oid 'hw.optional.arm64'
[       ] executing: xcrun xcdevice list --timeout 2
[   +6 ms] xcrun simctl list --json devices
[       ] executing: xcrun simctl list --json devices
[   +7 ms] /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR shell getprop
[ +180 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[       ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +431 ms] Generating /Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +89 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[ +133 ms] Starting incremental build...
[   +3 ms] Initializing file store
[  +28 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +19 ms] complete
[  +16 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Xperia Z in debug mode...
[  +16 ms] /Users/daniel/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
/Users/daniel/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
/Users/daniel/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata
-Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill /var/folders/ch/57dg6scn5rs592hmzcmbtprr0000gp/T/flutter_tools.iBaT0h/flutter_tool.sBfhPY/app.dill --packages .packages
-Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts
--track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build/cache.dill.track.dill
[  +49 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[  +47 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +1 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="com.example.testinstall" (Raw: "com.example.testinstall")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xa
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="testinstall" (Raw: "testinstall")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=28)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.testinstall.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.testinstall.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=42)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=52)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
                   E: intent-filter (line=56)
                     E: action (line=57)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=59)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=66)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[  +18 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +115 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[       ] --------- beginning of main
           01-09 14:17:22.627 I/getprop (19737): type=1400 audit(0.0:531): avc: denied { open } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7322 scontext=u:r:shell:s0
           tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[   +3 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[       ] --------- beginning of main
           01-09 14:17:22.627 I/getprop (19737): type=1400 audit(0.0:531): avc: denied { open } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7322 scontext=u:r:shell:s0
           tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  +21 ms] <- compile package:testinstall/main.dart
[  +14 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[  +37 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.1-6435776
           Installed as /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +5 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[  +67 ms] Building APK
[  +53 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +4 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +6 ms] Using gradle from /Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/android/gradlew.
[   +1 ms] /Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/android/gradlew mode: 33261 rwxr-xr-x.
[  +60 ms] executing: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
[  +28 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
[       ] {"CFBundleName":"Android
Studio","JVMOptions":{"ClassPath":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/bootstrap.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/extensions.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/util.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Conte
nts\/lib\/jdom.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/log4j.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/trove4j.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/jna.jar","JVMVersion":"1.8*,1.8+","WorkingDirectory
":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/bin","MainClass":"com.intellij.idea.Main","Properties":{"idea.paths.selector":"AndroidStudio3.6","idea.executable":"studio","idea.platform.prefix":"Andr
oidStudio","idea.home.path":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents"}},"NSDesktopFolderUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the user's Desktop
folder.","LSArchitecturePriority":["x86_64"],"CFBundleVersion":"AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135","CFBundleDevelopmentRegion":"English","NSCameraUsageDescription":"An application in
Android Studio requests access to the device's camera.","CFBundleDocumentTypes":[{"CFBundleTypeName":"Android Studio Project
File","CFBundleTypeExtensions":["ipr"],"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","CFBundleTypeIconFile":"studio.icns"},{"CFBundleTypeName":"All
documents","CFBundleTypeExtensions":["*"],"CFBundleTypeOSTypes":["****"],"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","LSTypeIsPackage":false}],"NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching":true,"CFBundl
ePackageType":"APPL","CFBundleIconFile":"studio.icns","NSHighResolutionCapable":true,"CFBundleShortVersionString":"3.6","NSMicrophoneUsageDescription":"An application in Android
Studio requests access to the device's microphone.","CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","CFBundleExecutable":"studio","NSLocationUsageDescription":"An application in Android
Studio requests access to the user's location
information.","LSRequiresNativeExecution":"YES","CFBundleURLTypes":[{"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","CFBundleURLName":"Stacktrace","CFBundleURLSchemes":["idea"]}],"CFBundleIdentifier
":"com.google.android.studio","LSApplicationCategoryType":"public.app-category.developer-tools","CFBundleSignature":"????","LSMinimumSystemVersion":"10.8","NSDocumentsFolderUsageD
escription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the user's Documents folder.","NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests
access to the user's Downloads folder.","NSNetworkVolumesUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to files on a network
volume.","CFBundleGetInfoString":"Android Studio 3.6, build AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135. Copyright JetBrains s.r.o., (c) 2000-2020","NSRemovableVolumesUsageDescription":"An
application in Android Studio requests access to files on a removable volume."}
[  +20 ms] executing: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
[ +186 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
[       ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b4-5784211, mixed mode)
[   +2 ms] executing: [/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/android/] /Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget-platform=android-arm -Ptarget=/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root
assembleDebug
[+3792 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[       ] > Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[  +69 ms] > Task :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[ +895 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[       ] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[ +101 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
[ +195 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[ +104 ms] > Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[  +93 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:mergeDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
[  +96 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[       ] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[       ] Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
[       ] > Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
[ +298 ms] > Task :app:assembleDebug
[       ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
[       ] 31 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 27 up-to-date
[ +448 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 6,4s)
[ +132 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory: '/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk'/app.apk
[  +34 ms] calculateSha: reading file took 33us
[ +878 ms] calculateSha: computing sha took 877us
[   +7 ms] ✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
[   +5 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[  +30 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +1 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="com.example.testinstall" (Raw: "com.example.testinstall")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xa
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="testinstall" (Raw: "testinstall")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=28)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.testinstall.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.testinstall.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=42)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=52)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
                   E: intent-filter (line=56)
                     E: action (line=57)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=59)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=66)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[   +9 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on Xperia Z.
[   +1 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR shell am force-stop com.example.testinstall
[ +171 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR shell pm list packages com.example.testinstall
[ +120 ms] Installing APK.
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[  +10 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.1-6435776
           Installed as /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +1 ms] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[  +11 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
[       ] executing: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s CB5A1QDUTR install -t -r
/Users/daniel/Projects/Flutter/Projects/testinstall/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
```

Comment: can you run "flutter run -v" and post the output?

Comment: I edited the output in